# C++: Interconnection between two classes

Tags: c++, class

Consider a case where  class B's object wants to send its ID to A's object. So A's ID can be set to B's ID. This can be consider as an placing an order. Then 
A wants to give B update about the status of its order (e.g. order dispatched). So B needs to have an attribute that should be set by A.In the code below I have the first piece that lets B place order at A, but the second piece that allows A to give update to B is missing.  My question is: " How can this be done?"

```
class A
{
private:
    string ID;

public:
    A()
    {
        ID = "empty";
    }

    void set_ID(string id)
    {
        ID = id;
    }
};

class B
{
private:
    string B_ID;

public:
    B(string id)
    {
        B_ID = id;
    }

    void put_request(A& a)
    {
        a.set_ID(B_ID);
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    B b("my ID");
    b.put_request(a);
}
```

Comment: Are you eventually having a problem with a missing forward declaration of `class B;`? Otherwise I can't tell what you're asking about. You provide another function in `A` that takes a `B&` as parameter, much the same as you did with `put_request()` in `B`.

Comment: As an idea, try this: declare both classes first, then in each class define a variable of the other class and interact with these variables.

Comment: `A` and `B` are pointing to the same ID eventually. You may want to have 2 ID variables in both of those classes to differentiate.

Comment: having some implementation of signal/slot would be very helpful, like QT or boost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure, if I understand your problem, but in case you can't make it work due to problems with names definition:

1. Separate implementation of methods from the body of each class.
2. Forward declare class, that is defined as second.

Also, you may want to declare two variables per each class:

1. `my_ID` holds id for this particular instance.
2. `ID` holds id, that is set by `put_request()` (perhaps initially set to `my_ID`?).

Now, the code:

```
class B;

class A
{
private:
    string my_ID;
    string ID;

public:
    A()
    : my_ID("empty")
    , ID(my_ID)
    { }

    void set_ID(string id);
    void put_request(B& b);
};

class B
{
private:
    string my_ID;
    string ID;

public:
    B(string id)
    : my_ID(id)
    , ID(my_ID)
    { }

    void set_ID(string id);
    void put_request(A& a);
};


void A::set_ID(string id) { this->ID = id; }

void A::put_request(B& b) { b.set_ID(this->my_ID); }


void B::set_ID(string id){ this->ID = id; }

void B::put_request(A& a) { a.set_ID(this->my_ID); }
```

Comment: @Adrian Ah, yes, sorry for these typo errors, fixed now.

Comment: The above answer is complete and correct, thank you Mateusz, but has  a minor typos error:  in class B, " void put_request(B& b); ", should be changed to " void put_request(A& a);  ".  Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

you can try on [ideone](http://ideone.com/CHZN2y)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
private:
    string ID;

public:
    A()
    {
        ID = "empty";
    }

    void set_ID(string id)
    {
        ID = id;
    }

    void write_ID()
    {
        cout<<"A id : "<<ID<<"\n";
    }
};

class B
{
private:
    string B_ID;

public:
    B(string id)
    {
        B_ID = id;
    }

    void put_request(A* a)
    {
        a->set_ID(B_ID);
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.write_ID();

    B b("my ID");
    b.put_request(&a);

    a.write_ID();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better not to send the B ID to A class, but give a pointer to the B object. Thus, A object can access B's ID and possibly other information of B class, needed to process the request.

Each of the objects should have its own ID. You shouldn't replace A's ID with that of B.

In order to place a request to A object, it's clearer to call A's method with a parameter of B class. Not other way around.

Example:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using std::string;

class B;

class A
{
private:
    string id;
    B* request;

public:
    A(const string& id)
    {
        this->id = id;
        request = NULL;
    }

    void set_request(B* request)
    {
        this->request = request;
    }

    string get_request_id() const;
};

class B
{
private:
    string id;

public:
    B(const string& id)
    {
        this->id = id;
    }

    string get_id() const
    {
        return id;
    }
};

string A::get_request_id() const
{
    if (!request)
        return string();
    return request->get_id();
}

int main()
{
    A a("A");
    B b("my ID");
    a.set_request(&b);
    std::cout << a.get_request_id() << std::endl;
}
```